# html email images not rendered in Gmail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

In Yahoo mail, HTML, images, and in-line CSS are rendered correctly.  In gmail, HTML is rendered, but the image alt tag appears instead of the image. In gmail, in-line css works sporadically, but not well.

The email is prepared in Codeigniter

here is the controller code:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';               $this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from($this->arr_mixed_info['str_user_email'], $this->arr_mixed_info['str_user_name']);
$this->email->to($this->arr_mixed_info['str_customer_email']);
$this->email->bcc($this->arr_mixed_info['str_user_email']);

$this->email->subject($this->arr_mixed_info['str_subject']);

$this->email->message($str_preview_invoice_page);
```

a review of questions already asked in stackoverflow does not reveal a solution

Comment: Are you putting the whole url in your html body of the mail. eg http://www.mydomain.com/images/myimage.jpg. It could be also some security issue with gmail thats why is not downloading the images.

Comment: In gmail, you have the option of "display images", gmail restricts the images by default, thats a gmail feature.